# Editing HTML input style with JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to recreate a version of wordle with my own code, and i have each letter set as its own input in html, im using a nested for loop to check to see whether the letter at a certain input is the same as the letter in the correct word and then highlighting it green. My for loop looks like this:

```
rowIndex1 = [square1, square2, square3, square4, square5, square6]

answer = "shorts"

for (let i = 0; i < rowIndex1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {
        if (rowIndex1[i] == answer[j]){
            rowIndex1[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        }
    }
}
<section id="row1">
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" onkeyup = "jump001(this, 'square2')" id ="square1" >
    <input type="text" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" onkeyup = "jump001(this, 'square3')" id ="square2" >
    <input type="text.css" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" onkeyup = "jump001(this, 'square4')" id ="square3" >
    <input type="text.css" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" onkeyup = "jump001(this, 'square5')" id ="square4" >
    <input type="text.css" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" onkeyup = "jump001(this, 'square6')" id ="square5" >
    <input type="text.css" maxlength="1" style="font-size: 30px; color: white; text-align: center;" onkeyup = "jump001(this, 'square1')" id ="square6" >
    </section>
```

Ignore the jump001 thats just to automove to next input when the user enters a character.
Each square that I have defined represents one input, but I can't seem to change the background color of the input box with my last line of code, the only thing I can do is select individual inputs by doing:

```
document.getElementById("square3").style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

but if I do this, the loop is useless, it seems as though I can't use the array in my first line to get through the HTML input elements, is there any way I can edit style in the loop using my `rowIndex1` array?

I appreciate all the help

Comment: You should show the related HTML codes as well.

Comment: how will "s" in answer ever be comparable to any object in rowIndex1? it seems that it is an array of objects not strings right

Comment: is a tile a letter or what?

Comment: each tile is one letter, correct. I already figured out that the loop works, my only issue is that I cant change the color of the input using      rowIndex1[i].style.backgroundColor           it looks like js doesnt actually go through the rowIndex1 array to look for which tile to change color

Comment: and I already have square1, square2, etc defined in a separate block of code. I defined each one as      square1 = document.getElementById("square1")

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the string into an array to loop it.

```
rowIndex1 = [square1, square2, square3, square4, square5, square6]

answer = "shorts"
const answerArray = answer .split("");

for (let i = 0; i < rowIndex1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < answerArray .length; j++) {
        if (rowIndex1[i] == answerArray [j]){
            document.getElementById(rowIndex1[i]).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        }
    }
}
```

This supposes that you have `<input id="square3" />`

**What i would do is modify the input ID and run a single loop**

```
<input id="tile_s" />
```

this way you can use just one loop without a comparative.

```js
answer = "shorts"
const answerArray = answer .split("");
for (let j = 0; j < answerArray .length; j++) {
  let elem = document.getElementById("tile_"+answerArray [j]);
  if(typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="tile_a" value="a">
<input id="tile_o" value="o">
<input id="tile_c" value="c">
<input id="tile_s" value="s">
<input id="tile_z" value="z">
<input id="tile_m" value="m">
```

Comment: Did you preset the value of each input to those letters? The problem Im having isn't with the loop itself necessarily, but how to iterate through each input with the loop and change the color to green if the input matches the letter in "answer". When i do document.getElementById(rowIndex1[i]).style.backgroundColor = 'green';    it doesn't recognize it and nothing changes

Comment: I preset it. see how i made the ID of each input correspond to the value, eg: `id="tile_a"` You don't share your HTML so I am not sure what you are doing or why. This is how I would handle it though.

Comment: Another thing is I could just run a ton of if statements and compare each square (each square I have represents an input of one letter that i compare to each character in "answer"). I could just do      if (square1 == answer[0]) { document.getElementById("square1").style.backgroundColor = 'green'; }                             but that seems really inefficient since I'd have to do that for every single input

Comment: I will share my HTML in the original post

Answer (score 0):

why you are looping `answer = "shorts"` while its just a single string ?

also you have to give us more of the code to see what those rowIndex1 are referring to and how they are being setup

but assuming they are ID's of inputs you could do this ( *`press on RunCode bellow to see the result`* ) :

```js
var rowIndex1 = ['square1', 'square2', 'square3', 'square4', 'square5', 'square6'];

var answer = "shorts";

for (let i = 0; i < rowIndex1.length; i++) {

         var input = document.getElementById(rowIndex1[i]);  
  
        if (input.value == answer){
            input.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            }
}
```

```html
<input id="square1" value="">
<input id="square2" value="shorts">
<input id="square3" value="">
<input id="square4" value="shorts">
<input id="square5" value="">
<input id="square6" value="long">
```

Comment: im looping each character in "shorts" and comparing each character with each square that I have in my rowIndex1. Each square I have represents one letter that the user inputs, so I compare square1 to the first letter in "shorts" and so on. I use the second for loop to loop through the characters in answer, ill try to use your solution

Answer (score 0):

To compare each character, you first need to call `.split('')` on the answer string to turn it into an array of single characters. Then in a single loop, in each iteration you have the index of each item to compare is the same (`rowIndex1[i]` vs. `answer[i]`).
The following snippet will highlight each input that has the correct letter for its position:

```js
var rowIndex1 = ['square1', 'square2', 'square3', 'square4', 'square5', 'square6'];

var answer = "shorts".split('');

for (let i = 0; i < rowIndex1.length; i++) {
  var input = document.getElementById(rowIndex1[i]);
  if (input.value == answer[i]) {
    input.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input id="square1" value="s">
<input id="square2" value="h">
<input id="square3" value="t">
<input id="square4" value="r">
<input id="square5" value="o">
<input id="square6" value="z">
```

Comment: You're actually insane thank you so much, this fixed the problem I've been having for so long